# How can I use NSMutableArray in a detail ViewController?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am stuck with a problem and can't find a decent solution. I am trying to add a name in parent ViewController and show them in a `UITableView` but to add a new name I go to a AddVC where I add a name via a `UITextField` and I want to add the name in the `NSMutableArray` from the parentVC.

Comment: You want to add the name in a view controller, and have the name passed back to the parent controller?

Comment: yes . i want to add a object in childVC and then show it in ParentVC

Comment: You code the table view's `dataSource` delegate so that it refers to the NSMutableArray for it's row values, then, after updating the array with a new value, you signal `reloadData` to the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Let me restate what I think you're asking: You have a ParentVC and you want to segue to a ChildVC that will present a UITextField to enter a name. Once the name is entered, you want to return the name back to the ParentVC. If this is correct then within your ChildVC prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
      // if you're using a nav controller (modal)
      //UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
      //ParentVC *destinationVC = (ParentVC *)navController.topViewController;

      // if you're not using a nav controller (push)
      ParentVC *destinationVC = (ParentVC *)segue.destinationViewController;

      // assuming you have a public property in your ParentVC.h such as:
      // @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *theNewName;

      destinationVC.theNewName = myAddNameTextField.text;
}
```

Comment: prepareForSegue is not called when dismissing a modal or popping off the navigation stack.

Answer (score -1):

Take an `NSMutableArray` as a `property` in your `AppDelegate` . Always fetch the Array from `AppDelegate`. If you add something. Just add in this global mutable array. This way it won't matter where you add object in array and where from you fetch .

Comment: i am trying but its not working can you show me how ? thank you .